# How to loop in a makefile, OUTSIDE OF A RULE

Tags: gnu-make

I'd like to perform certain initialization actions, outside of a rule (involving the reading of sub-files and info present inside), in a makefile.

That is, I have several directories, in which I have created "module.mk" files (one in each directory), which are included by the Makefiles present in these directories. They describe a number of things, including the name of certain products. Now, these products are stored in the same variable in each module.mk file (like: "PRODUCTS:=foo bar")

What I would like to do would be, in the Makefile from the parent directory, to include in turn each of these files, then be able to make some kind of treatment on the PRODUCTS variable from that file. Like, add them (with the appropriate path) to a list of files, which I could in turn use in a rule to build something else.

So, for instance:

Directory A: module.mk, containing the line PRODUCTS:=foo bar

Directory B: module.mk, containing the line PRODUCTS:=baz

Then, in the Makefile from the parent directory, having something like
DIRECTORIES:=A B
$(foreach DIR,$(DIRECTORIES),include $(DIR)/module.mk; FILES+=$(PRODUCTS))

I'd like to have some more treatment (modifying the PRODUCTS from the given makefile, by adding appropriate paths, and other things, but the "base" problem is to be able to create separate lines from a single $(foreach) call.
Right now, when I try something similar, I get a make error which tells me
"Makefile:515: *** missing separator.  Stop."

Are there solutions to do it the way I had envisioned, or will I have to take the hard way, and do it inside of a rule, having to parse the files myself (using grep and other command-line tools) ?

Comment: You may want to take a look at [gmtt](https://github.com/markpiffer/gmtt) which has a lot of service functions you may find useful when programming `make` the way you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `eval` for this.  See these sections of the GNU make manual:

- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Parsing-Makefiles.html
- https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html

and also you might find this series of blog posts interesting (start with the bottom one, that was written first):

- https://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/

In your situation you'll want to create a variable using `define` then use `eval` within a `foreach` loop.  Something like:

```
define INCLUDE_ONE
PRODUCTS :=
include $(dir)/module.mk
FILES += $(PRODUCTS)
endef

$(foreach dir,$(DIRECTORIES),$(eval $(value INCLUDE_ONE)))
```

Alternatively if you have more than one "argument" you could use `call` instead of `value`, but you need to escape the `$(PRODUCTS)` variable reference in your `define`.